# How to declare JS variables with names that ends with a question mark?

Tags: javascript

In Ruby, we are allowed to declare variables containing question mark like this: `panelHidden?` Is there any way to do this in JS? It gives me an error when I do this.

Comment: This is not possible as it's invalid syntax

Comment: @DacreDenny Technically it is possible (ex `window['test?'] = 'weee'`), but you'd be forced to use array notation to access the variable, which is ugly

Comment: The question mark character is not a valid JavaScript identifier character.

Comment: @Taplar true, but I don't think that's what the author has in mind :)

Comment: @Taplar That's a property name, not a variable. (Although in Ruby, `panelHidden?` looks like method name indeed)